# Performance optimization - Implementing Concurrent builder pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a complex builder pattern implemented in the code similar to the last one in [this](https://dev.to/crisgoncalves84/the-fluent--facade-builder-pattern-9g) URL. The purpose of the builders are to construct the SQL query based on the object properties.

Something like

```
PersonQueryBuilder person =
                new PersonQueryBuilder.Builder()
                        .BuildAddressClause(request.PersonInformation.Address)
                        .BuildBankAccountClause(request.PersonInformation.BankAccountInformation)
                        .BuildAClause(request.Something)
                        .BuildBClause(request.Something)
                        .build();
```

I was thinking, instead of sequential execution of these builder logics, it would be more efficient if I could run them with

```
TaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
{
// Create builder here so that the builder pattern stays the same, but the process runs concurrently.
});
```

Is there any way/example that can demonstrate similar behavior?

Comment: You're building strings, so this must effectively take no time already: running them on separate threads will probably take longer, what with the marshalling required.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at Eric Lippert's [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) - _"don’t make performance-based changes unless you’ve identified a performance problem."_

Comment: Do you have an actual problem? Becuse StartNew will likely create them?

Comment: Well! For 5 out of 13 builders, there are 3 service calls. Usually the 2 3rd party service API takes time (m+n). And rest of the builders are straightforward string manipulation and few LINQ. As a result, the builders take time and my API SLA becomes m+n+x; x being the service API operation time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, with recent C# you use `Task.Run(...)` instead of `TaskFactory.StartNew(...)` to start a background task running the function.
However, this won't make builders run in parallel, for parallelization of CPU-bound work (I assume the builders don't perform any disk/network I/O) you use the `Parallel` class, `Parallel.Invoke` seems to fit your case.

However, when using Parallel class, you need to make sure the different builders don't mutate the same state, e.g. don't manipulate a shared `StringBuilder` representing the SQL query. If you need to mutate same state you can introduce locks for thread-safety where needed, however make sure the parallelization is indeed justified.